# How to delete string or digits after certain pattern?

Tags: r, regex, string-substitution

If there is a vector x that is,

```
x <- c('/name12/?ad_2','/name13/?ad_3','/name14/?ad_4')
```

Is there a way to delete the following numbers after 'ad_'?

so the converted x appears as

```
'/name12/?ad_' '/name13/?ad_' '/name14/?ad_'
```

I was trying to use `gsub` function but it didn't work because of the digits followed by 'name'.

Comment: Try `gsub("_\\d", "_", x)`

Comment: When you tried to use the `gsub` function, what did you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex with `sub` (since you perform a single search and replace, you do not need `gsub`) and use a pattern depending on what you need to include or exclude in the result.

You might use `"(\\?ad_)[0-9]+$"` to remove `?ad_` + digits and replace with `"\\1"` to restore the `?ad_` value, or just match the `_` and then digits (and replace with `_`).

See demo code:

```
> x <- c('/name12/?ad_2','/name13/?ad_3','/name14/?ad_4')
> sub("(\\?ad_)[0-9]+$", "\\1", x)
[1] "/name12/?ad_" "/name13/?ad_" "/name14/?ad_"
> sub("_[0-9]+$", "_", x)
[1] "/name12/?ad_" "/name13/?ad_" "/name14/?ad_"
```

See the [regex demo](https://ideone.com/6RjQSu)

**Pattern details**:

- `_` - matches an underscore
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more (due to the `+` quantifier matching one or more occurrences, as many as possible)
- `$` - the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Since the prefix is the same length for all of them:

```
x <- c('/name12/?ad_2','/name13/?ad_3','/name14/?ad_4')

substr(x,1,12)
```

> [1] "/name12/?ad_" "/name13/?ad_" "/name14/?ad_"

Otherwise I would `grep` it.